# Why a controller method is acting as POST instead GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a **kendoGrid** that read data with `.Read(r => r.Action("CargaNotificacionesPorCliente", "bff").Data("getClaveCliente")))`, the call works and the values are displayed in the grid correctly, nothing weird here.

[image: kendoGrid]

When I open the Chrome DevTools it show the following error:

> POST http://localhost:52881/bff/CargaNotificacionesPorCliente 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

I don't know why is marking it as a **POST** instead **GET**.

This my method (actually works)

```
public ActionResult CargaNotificacionesPorCliente([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string numeroCliente)
{
    bff.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var lstNotificaciones = new List<NotificacionesModel>();

    var lstNoPartesNuevas = bff.inspListaNoPartes
        .Where(x => x.codeCustomer == numeroCliente &&
                    x.Estatus == Constantes.EstatusNumParteNuevo &&
                    x.VistoCte == false)
        .Include(i => i.CustomerCUSTOMER)
        .ToList();

    var cantidadComentariosNuevos = bff.inspCommentNoPartes
        .Count(x => x.inspListaNoParte.codeCustomer == numeroCliente &&
                    x.Visto == false &&
                    x.Usuario != User.Identity.Name);

    if (lstNoPartesNuevas.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in lstNoPartesNuevas)
        {
            if (lstNotificaciones.All(a => a.IdCustomer != item.IdCustomer))
            {
                lstNotificaciones.Add(new NotificacionesModel
                {
                    Cantidad = lstNoPartesNuevas.Count(x => x.IdCustomer == item.IdCustomer && x.Estatus == Constantes.EstatusNumParteNuevo && x.VistoSup == false) + cantidadComentariosNuevos,
                    Name = item.CustomerCUSTOMER.name,
                    IdCustomer = item.IdCustomer,
                    IdNumPart = item.IdNumPart
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return Json(lstNotificaciones.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this is the **Preview tab** of the error in the DevTools

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

But as I said, it's weird because it works

Tried adding **[HttpGet]** but doesn't work, in fact the method is never called with that annotation.

**EDIT:**

I did the binding by this way:

```
$("#Notificaciones").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); // Read data
$("#Notificaciones").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1); // Go to page 1
```

I removed the second line (`.dataSource.page(1);`) and now the error disappeared, but how this affected the call?, I can't figure it out

Comment: What happens if you mark the action with `[HttpPost]`? And why would you this it should be a `get`, if you look at the parameters `DataSourceRequest ` it is a strongly typed object, passing such an object in a `get` means posting entire data in url. So I think `kendo` guys made it as post.

Comment: In the same view I have another grid that load data with the same parameters, but the error is displayed only for this one. Btw, tried with `[HttpPost]` and the console now shows the following: `Failed to load resource http://localhost:52881/bff/CargaNotificacionesPorCliente: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` @ramiramilu

Comment: I am confused, you have two grids - one grid working and other not working? Post entire code of not working grid along with its action.

Comment: What was the data which got send in that request, use chrome developer tools to capture it.

Comment: 2 grids are reading data at the same time with the same parameter **(numeroCliente)**, this is the call of the second grid **wich don't display any errors** `.Read(r => r.Action("CargaNumeroDePartePorCliente", "bff").Data("getClaveCliente")))`. Here is where I make the binding `$("#Notificaciones").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
$("#NumerosDeParte").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();`. But as I said **both** grids works correctly, the issue is the error that the **first** grid is displaying @ramiramilu

Comment: This is the data I'm sending in the request: `/bff/CargaNotificacionesPorCliente?sort=&group=&filter=&numeroCliente=LEAC01++++&page=NaN` @ramiramilu

Comment: Whoa, the error disappeared when I removed a line `$("#Notificaciones").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1);` Could you explain why? @ramiramilu

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do something like this

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Banques").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
.PageSize(8)
)
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/post-vs-get-request

Comment: Still having error. I think I figured out how to handle the error, just updated my post. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ramiramilu `.Type(HttpVerbs.Get))` he didn't specify the HttpVerb in the original statement

Answer (score 1):

In the tool you are using, make sure that the HTTP verb is selected as Get. See below for a screenshot from Chrome's Postman
[image]